# Eclipse is not recommending fixes to errors

Tags: eclipse

I recently purchased a new computer, and have a new install of the JDK and Eclipse. My old Eclipse install used to suggest/recommend clickable fixes to errors. My new install only shows errors.

How can I convince Eclipse to show me those clickable fixes?

Comment: Eclipse version, OS...

Comment: check whether jdk setup is right..

Comment: jdk is set up correctly. i see java -version fine. OS = windows. Eclipse Europa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using an Eclipse version that is more than 5 years old. Please immediately replace it by a new version from the [eclipse website](http://www.eclipse.org/), as that will probably solve this and many other issues you might have with Eclipse.